# Is there a utility for validating makefiles?

Tags: makefile

I'd like to validate my hand-written makefiles, to make sure they work as intended on a variety of platforms.  Is there a utility I can use to warn me of idiosyncrasies that might get in the way?

Comment: You want a utility that will tell you whether a piece of software will work *as intended?* Do you plan to give it control of a nuclear arsenal?

Comment: The easiest would be to write tests for Makefiles, i.e. put the into a specific environment and expect pre-defined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as far as I'm aware of.

The best thing to do is respect the old rule "port early; port often".  Try building your application on other platforms as soon as possible, and re-do it whenever you have the opportunity.  That'll shake out portability bugs in your code, and validate the Makefile as a side-effect.

That said, it's wise to limit yourself to conservative Makefile features as much as possible.  You might want to look at the [POSIX make manpage](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/make.html) (though I'd advise you to use the `%.foo: %.bar` rules rather the nominally standard `.bar.foo:` rules), and the [portable make programming](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/autoconf.html#Portable-Make) section of the autoconf manual is full of good advice.

Oh, and you know that [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) is a Good Thing, yes?

Answer (score 0):

sorry bro but .... not sure if there could be any single code use eveywhere code, this is one of the strongest and the weakest points of Unix .... there are so many different flavours of the OS itself and the implementations of Make Utility -- GNU is just one of them and so is the open solaris form (small differences), but they do share a host of common features

there are features of GNU Make that are available only if you invoke your makefile descriptor with a GNU make , its same for other OS varients of make utility as well  .. with constraints like these

"a thorough testing in all the possible systems you want it to work is the only solution that comes to my mind"